# BAT - как проверить состояние процесса (не отвечает/работает)

Tags: bat, процесс

Собственно в заголовке я выложил всю информацию.
Нужен батник для проверки состояния процесса, если он не отвечает рестартать его.

Comment: да вот совершенно не ясно, что нужно. Каковы критерии "не работающего" процесса? Загрузка CPU >99%, изменился заголовок окна связанного с процессом, объем ОЗУ процесса ниже требуемого и т.д.?